How to solve multi-regional apps in regard to decimal seperator
I have a fairly simple Power Apps app where the user is expected to input a decimal number like 0.5 for hours worked that will end up in a Sharepoint List.
On PC you have the whole keyboard available, so "," or "." is less of an issue.
On the IPhone on the other hand, the keypad only show the decimal seperator of the actual regional settings from the phone. And among the users the regional settings used varies from user to user. My app does not allow the "," to be entered into the box.
Is there a recommandation on how to solve this?
